# What are the differences between BitBlaze and BAP?

Tags: tools, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis, binary-analysis

[BitBlaze](http://bitblaze.cs.berkeley.edu/) and [BAP](http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/) are two platforms to perform binary analysis. And, if I understand well, they are sharing lots of common features. What are their respective main features and in what do they differ from each other ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BAP is mostly a rewrite of BitBlaze, so feature-wise there are many common features.  However, many of these have been re-written or re-designed for BAP.

**Common features:**

- Lifting of usermode, x86 instructions
- Datafow analysis module
- Dominator analysis
- CFG and SSA representations
- Optimization framework
- Verification condition generation
- Dependency graphs
- Slicing

I am a BAP developer, so I can mainly attest to what is new in BAP since we split.  However, I don't think BitBlaze has (publicly) added new features since then.

**New in BAP**:

- Formally defined semantics for the IL
- PIN-based user-level taint tracking and tracing tool
- Integration with LLVM
- Native instruction lifting (i.e., in OCaml)

**Only in BitBlaze:**

- TEMU system-level taint tracking and tracing tool

Comment: thx for technical details, Ed. +1 :)